# how to compare two hashmaps by their keys and list of values in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two different hashmap with Map<String, ArrayList> format , how to compare key first and then comparing their values are same or not.

Comment: you can use `Map.equals()` that is `map1.equals(map2)`

Comment: What do you mean by “comparing their values are same or not”? You *either* want to compare *or* you want to know if they’re equal. Which is it?

Comment: @Bohemian for the same key  value equal or not

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply trying to test if all keys and all values in the maps are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then this should work:

```
boolean equalMaps = map1.equals(map2);
```

If want to test that entries with the same key have equal values, then:

```
boolean equalValues = map1.entrySet().stream()
                          .filter(e -> map2.get(e.getKey()) != null)
                          .allMatch(e -> e.getValue().equals(map2.get(e.getKey()));
```

(Note: the above is not the most efficient solution possible.  The `filter` eliminates cases where the key is not present in `map2` which would otherwise cause the `allMatch` to fail.)

And there are other solutions for other tests that you may want to perform.

Note the above solutions assume that the value type's `equals(Object)` method has the right semantics for your vaguely stated *"comparing their values are same or not"* requirement.